# Java switch statements

Tags: java, switch-statement

Was just wondering if I could do something like this in java with switch statements?

```
switch(a && b){

case 1:

//

case 2:

//

}
```

Comment: No you can't switch based on a boolean value.

Comment: so as per your username, when I say 'Don't try it yourself', you really won't try it.

Comment: What are `a` and `b` and why would you expect `&&` to produce either 1 or 2 when this operator returns a `boolean`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can, but not with logical AND (&&). You probably meant to use bit-wise AND (as your case clauses suggest) :

```
switch(a & b) {
case 1: 
case 2:   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of a & b ?
If it is `boolean` then it won't work, `switch` works with `int`.
If they are `int` then you must use single `&` operation and not a `&&`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a,b;
    a=5;
    b=2;
    switch(a & b){

    case 1:

    //

    case 2:

    //

    }
```